# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Currencies'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on blazor server. I have the following class structure for my project.

I have for this error three classes.

`ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public Guid ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required")]
    public string Surname { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Salary pay date is required")]
    public DateTime? SalaryPaymentDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Salary amount is required")]
    public Decimal? SalaryAmount { get; set; }
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Currency is required")]
    public Guid? CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public Currency? Currency { get; set; }
    public List<CreditCard>? CreditCards { get; set;}
    public List<Saving>? Savings { get; set;}
    public List<Expense>? Expenses { get; set;}
}
```

`Currency` class:

```
public class Currency
{
    public Guid CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string CurrencyAbbreviation { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser>? ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

```
I seeded the currency class with three values namely:
- USD
- ZAR
- Euro

`Savings` class:
 
    public class Saving
    {
        public Guid SavingID { get; set; }
        public List<Goal>? Goals { get; set; }
        public Guid? ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser? ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

So what I am trying to do is when you open the savings view for the first time and the Get method returns 0 values I create a new `SavingObject`.

In this `SavingObject`, I assign the `CurrentUser` which is passed as a cascading parameter and it does have a value.

Then I run my `AddMethod` to create the saving object. Here is the method:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public ApplicationUser? CurrentUser { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Savings = await savingsservice.Get();

    if (Savings?.Count > 0)
        SavingObject = Savings.FirstOrDefault();
    else
    {
        SavingObject = new Saving();
        SavingObject.ApplicationUser = CurrentUser!;
        SavingObject.ApplicationUserID = CurrentUser!.ApplicationUserID;
        await savingsservice.Add(SavingObject);
        DataChanged();
    }

    Goals = await goalsservice.Get();
}
```

But it then crashes with the following message once the add method is run:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Currencies'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Currencies'. The duplicate key value is (c80b1fe5-7d94-4fc5-8328-706db7f29a18).
>
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ApplicationUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ApplicationUsers'. The duplicate key value is (1d03c731-3034-498b-fef5-08db0eaad3f6).

I understand that it states cannot insert duplicate key for the user and currency but why does it want to insert a duplicate key I don't understand because I am assigning the user so it already has the ID and the `CurrencyID`?

Also my `Savings` table is empty and I only have one `applicationUser` in my table which has one `Currency`.

Can someone please assist as I can't find any answer online.

I have googled the problem but I can't find my specific problem online therefore I am creating a question.

I have also setup the `dbcontext` as I thought this might have been the problem.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Savings)
        .WithOne(a => a.ApplicationUser)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ApplicationUserID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(a => a.CreditCards)
        .WithOne(a => a.ApplicationUser)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ApplicationUserID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Expenses)
        .WithOne(a => a.ApplicationUser)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.ApplicationUserID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Here is my Savings.cs service:

```
namespace MoneyTracker.Services
{
    public interface ISavingsService
    {
        Task<List<Saving>> Get();
        Task<Saving> Get(Guid id);
        Task<Saving> Add(Saving Saving);
        Task<Saving> Update(Saving Saving);
        Task<Saving> Delete(Guid id);
        void DetachEntity(Saving Saving);
    }
    public class SavingsService : ISavingsService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public SavingsService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<Saving>> Get()
        {
            return await _context.Savings
                .Include(a => a.Goals)
                .AsSplitQuery()
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<Saving> Get(Guid id)
        {
            var Saving = await _context.Savings.FindAsync(id);
            return Saving;
        }

        public async Task<Saving> Add(Saving Saving)
        {
            _context.Savings.Add(Saving);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Saving;
        }
        public async Task<Saving> Update(Saving Saving)
        {
            _context.Entry(Saving).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Saving;
        }
        public async Task<Saving> Delete(Guid id)
        {
            var Saving = await _context.Savings.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Savings.Remove(Saving);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Saving;
        }
        public void DetachEntity(Saving Saving)
        {
            _context.Entry(Saving).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to change the render-mode to "Server" instead of "ServerPrerendered" in the _Host.cshtml file.

Comment: I did change it to server but still did not work.

Comment: It may be related to forgetting the await/async keyword somewhere. Please upload the `savingsservice` code in the answer for further review. And also please change the `SavingObject = Savings.FirstOrDefault();` to `SavingObject =  await Savings.FirstOrDefaultAsync();`. When you use the Async method such as `OnInitializeAsync` so any methods that you used must be Async.

Comment: See that is not the problem as my get works 100%, the problem is in the Add section of the method. But I will add the service to the question

Comment: The service is the problem, and actually causes that and a whole lot more problems. First of all this is neither a Service nor a Repository, it's a low-level Data Access Object that performs CRUD operations. It's used when you have to talk to the database directly using ADO.NET  EF Core is a high-level ORM though. A DbContext is already a multi-entity Repository and disconnected Unit-Of-Work. A DbContext instance keeps track of all its entities and persists all changes in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. By calling `SaveChanges` on every change you lose transactions

Comment: `OnInitializedAsync` has a common transaction bug, ORMs or not. It tries to check for existence and add a new object on the client side. What happens if another call creates that object between `Count` and `INSERT` though? If the same key is used, you'll get the error you just posted. If a new key is created, you can end up with duplicate rows. To avoid this applications use `INSERT` with a `WHERE` clause. EF Core does this too.

Comment: This specific exception is caused because `Add` in an ORM doesn't do what CRUD classes assume. It doesn't INSERT anything, but starts tracking the entire object graph, ie the immediate object and all its relations, in the `Added` state. That includes `SavingObject.ApplicationUser`. When `SaveChanges` is called, both `Savings` and `ApplicationUser` will be inserted to the database. Use `Update` instead to track objects without a PK as `Added` and those with an existing key as `Modified`.

Comment: Has `CurrentUser` come from the same DbContext there wouldn't be a problem, because the context would already track `CurrentUser`. The code doesn't show where `SavingsService` comes from or what its lifetime is, but it's obvious that `CurrentUser` didn't come from the same service instance

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to resolve my problem.

The reason the problem had occurred was because when I assigned the `SavingObject` to the `GoalObject` it was not added to the context. So when I was trying to run the add method on the `goalObject` it also attempted to add the `savingObject` because it was not found on the context.

Also the thing I noted in the `AddMethod` of the `Service` was that when I would add a new goal and I opended the `GoalObject` with a breakpoint I could see the `SavingsObject.Goals count was 1` not null. With the following method it resolved the problem.

```
var saving = await _context.Savings.FindAsync(goal.SavingID);
var user = await _context.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(goal.Saving!.ApplicationUserID);
if (saving == null || user == null)
{
   throw new Exception("Saving with the specified ID not found");
}

saving.ApplicationUser = user;
goal.Saving = saving;
_context.Goals.Add(goal);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
return goal;
```

When I inspected here after I assigned the `goal.Saving = saving` the count of the goals was null and this prevented the error Duplicate PK error

I really hope this helps someone as I struggled a lot with this error.